# Git branch and tag my release(s)

Tags: git

I’m new to git and slowly getting the concepts of git. I have a situation where I have my project releases packaged as zip files (~10) and shared to me, I’m having it in my local machine(zip files).
My goal is to create a git bare repo and to create three branches

1. Develop
2. Prod
3. Test

And then “tag” those 10 packages to “Prod” branch in an order (oldest to newest) .

I’m aware of how to create a bare repository, but would like to know how to create 3 branches? And how to “tag” my 10 releases (extracted zip) to the Prod branch only one after another.

Comment: You said "you want to create a bare repo" so you want to have no working directory in git and use it as a server or do you missused the word here? Because bare git repos exists in git.

Answer (score 0):

To create new branches use `git branch <new branch name >`
Use this command 3 times to create the 3 branches you want. After that you want to tag the branches which is actually only tagging the last commit of the branch. 
First of all you are now on the master branch which is the default branch. Use `git branch` to view all the branches( master should be green because you're checking it out). So you need to checkout the other branch. Use `git checkout <branch Name>` to go to that branch & then use `git tag <tag name>` to tag it. Repeat the last 2 steps for all the branches & you're done. 
NOTE : Don't forget to always use `git branch` to know on which branch you are before doing anything

Comment: To tag you're 10 releases you can commit them one after another in any branch & just tag each commit. That will result in 10 commits & 10 tags

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git checkout -b <branchname>`?

Comment: git checkout -b <branchName> is the combination between git branch <branchName> & git checkout <branchName>. It creates the branch & directly checks it out